# Use jQuery to update cell values under a specific th to links

Tags: jquery

I need to use jquery to loop through the following table and turn the cell values under the "Account Name" th into hyperlinks.

```
<table id="exampleTable">
 <tr>
     <th>Type</th>
     <th>Account Name</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>Type 1</td>
      <td>Account Name 1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>Type 2</td>
      <td>Account Name 2</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Type 3</td>
      <td>Account Name 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>Type 4</td>
      <td>Account Name 4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>Type 5</td>
      <td>Account Name 5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>Type 6</td>
      <td>Account Name 6</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I'm currently using this Jquery code to get the index of the Account Name th and then loop through each table row to find the td that shares that index.

```
 let title;
 $("th").each(function() {
   if ($.trim($(this).text()) == "Account Name") {
      title = $(this).index();
   }
 });
 $("tr").each(function() {
   let link = $.trim($(this).find("td:eq(" + title + ")").text());
   let anchor = "<a href='http://" + link + "'>" + link + "</a>";
   $(this).find("td:eq(" + title + ")").html(anchor);
 });
```

The problem that I'm facing is that this table is paginated. The first two rows show up on page one and the next two so up on page 2 and so on. My current jQuery code is correctly changing the table cell text for Account Name 1 and Account Name 2 to a link on page 1, however these links are then duplicated on each successive page. Another words, on page two the Account Name 3 text and Account Name 4 text are being changed to links that say Account Name 1 and Account Name 2. This is occuring on every page.

I'm not sure if I need to add a third loop like

```
 $("td").each(function() {

 });
```

or if my current code just needs to be changed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noPrevious() || ngDisabled 
    }" class="ng-scope" style="">
     <a sp-focus-changer="#pageLink-1" sp-focus-changer-click="true" href="" 
        aria-disabled="false" ng-click="selectPage(page - 1, $event)" aria- 
        label="Previous Page" role="menuitem">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" role="presentation"></i>
     </a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an additional loop, your code works well with the example table you provided. There is some specific thing with the library you are using to create the pagination. Will be better if you provide a live example in codepen.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to that. This data I provided was a representation of a table I'm working with in a Web Application known as Sailpoint. Sailpoint allows developers to use jquery snippets to update DOM elements but it doesn't give us access to the actual code. The only additional info I have comes from when I inspect the pagination links. I've updated the code above to display this.

Comment: I made some changes and added debug code which could help to find the issue:
```
$("tr").each(function(index, element) {
   var link = $.trim($(element).find("td:eq(" + title + ")").text());
   var anchor = "<a href='http://" + link + "'>" + link + "</a>";
   console.log(element);
   console.log($(element).find("td:eq(" + title + ")").text());
   console.log(link);
   $(element).find("td:eq(" + title + ")").html(anchor);
 });
```